# Creating Histogram in R not showing any bar

Tags: r, plot, histogram

Just learning R and need to create histogram using hist(). Below is my original R-script (hypothetical data):

```
x <- c(25130250, 26054121, 28074512, 36025050, 35013655)
y <- c(1:5)
hist(x, main = "Trafic Per Year", xlab="x-value", ylab = "y-Value")
```

This returns: [image]

What I wanted is for the chart to:

1. show the y (i.e. 1, 2, 3,4, 5) on the x-axis
2. show the x (i.e. 25130250,etc) on the y-axis reduced to million (i.e. 25, 26, 28, etc.)

So, I modified the script as follows and now its not showing any bar.

```
hist(x, xlim = c(1,5), ylim = c(25,37), breaks = 5,freq = T,
     main = "Trafic Per Year",xlab="x-value",ylab = "y-Value")
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `barplot(round(x / 1000000), names.arg = y)`

Comment: `hist` takes unaggregated data. It looks like your data is already aggregated so @bouncyball's answer is probably most appropriate

Comment: `barplot` is an option for aggregated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you serve what I did was assign y to x, and x to y

```
y <- c(25130250, 26054121, 28074512, 36025050, 35013655)
x <- c(1:5)

barplot(round(y/1000000,3), main = "Trafic Per Year", xlab="x-value", ylab = "y-Value", las = 2)
axis(1,at = c(0.7,1.9,3.1,4.3,5.5),labels=1:5)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you wanted a barplot rather than a histogram:

```
 vals <- barplot( round(x/1000000), main = "Trafic Per Year", xlab="x-value", ylab = "y-Value",
                 horiz=TRUE)
 vals   # the function returns the midpoint location of the bars
  #-------
     [,1]
[1,]  0.7
[2,]  1.9
[3,]  3.1
[4,]  4.3
[5,]  5.5
  #-----
 axis(2, at=vals,labels=1:5)
```

[image]